# Iterate through Object's own Strings & Trim each

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, trim

I have multiple large objects which each have about 60 strings. I have to trim all those strings, and I'd like to do so without having to go this.mystring = this.mystring.Trim(). Instead, I'm looking for a way to automatically have each object discover its own strings and then perform the operation.

I know a little bit about reflection, but not enough, but I think this is possible?

Also, I'm not sure if this matters, but some string properties are read-only (only have a getter), so those properties would have to be skipped.

Help?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, it's easy enough to get all the properties, and find out which ones are strings and writable. LINQ makes it even easier.

```
var props = instance.GetType()
                    .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
                    // Ignore non-string properties
                    .Where(prop => prop.PropertyType == typeof(string))
                    // Ignore indexers
                    .Where(prop => prop.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0)
                    // Must be both readable and writable
                    .Where(prop => prop.CanWrite && prop.CanRead);

foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
{
    string value = (string) prop.GetValue(instance, null);
    if (value != null)
    {
        value = value.Trim();
        prop.SetValue(instance, value, null);
    }
}
```

You may want to only set the property if trimming actually makes a difference, to avoid redundant computations for complex properties - or it may not be an issue for you.

There are various ways of improving the performance if necessary - things like:

- Simply caching the relevant properties for each type
- Using `Delegate.CreateDelegate` to build delegates for the getters and setters
- Possibly using expression trees, although I'm not sure whether they'd help here

I wouldn't take any of those steps unless performance is actually a problem though.

Comment: I thought property trees are automatically cached if not in debug mode? I've read that a few times. Is this not true?

Comment: In this case, `Expression` would be a pain, even in 4.0; combining multiple `Action<T,string>` into a single delegate would work well, though.

Comment: @Alex - lambda expressions in the *source* can do some clever things, using a backing delegate field. However, AFAIK that is not true of trees built manually and compiled (`Compile`) at runtime.

Comment: your example misses a cast from prop.GetValue to String

Answer (score 3):

Something like:

```
    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties(
        BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public))
    {
        if (prop.CanRead && prop.CanWrite && prop.PropertyType == typeof(string)
            && (prop.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0)) // watch for indexers!
        {
            var s = (string)prop.GetValue(obj, null);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) s = s.Trim();
            prop.SetValue(obj, s, null);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The parameterless `Type.GetProperties()` call includes static properties, which I *suspect* shouldn't be included here.

Comment: @Jon - good point, thanks. I won't mention `IsReadable` ;p Also - you might want to check for indexers.

Comment: Could you explain why you check for prop.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0? What does this do?

Comment: @Alex: It stops it from picking up indexers.

Comment: @Alex - an indexer is something like `public string this[int i] {get {...} set {...}}`, which surfaces as a special kind of property.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessary to make `IEnumerable` check in the props-loop and if actual instance is a `IEnumerable`, props are ignored. Fix for `IEnumerable` part:

```
private void TrimWhitespace(object instance)
{
    if (instance != null)
    {
        if (instance is IEnumerable)
        {
            foreach (var item in (IEnumerable)instance)
            {
                TrimWhitespace(item);
            }
        }

        var props = instance.GetType()
                .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
            // Ignore indexers
                .Where(prop => prop.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0)
            // Must be both readable and writable
                .Where(prop => prop.CanWrite && prop.CanRead);

        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
        {
            if (prop.GetValue(instance, null) is string)
            {
                string value = (string)prop.GetValue(instance, null);
                if (value != null)
                {
                    value = value.Trim();
                    prop.SetValue(instance, value, null);
                }
            }
            else 
                TrimWhitespace(prop.GetValue(instance, null));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So to expand on this a little, I have a complex object with Lists of Lists and I wanted to traverse that and trim all of the child string objects as well.  I'm posting what I did as of what I built on from @Jon did in his answer.  I'm curious if there was a better way to do it or if I missed something obvious.

The objects I have are more complex than this but it should illustrate what I was trying.

```
public class Customer
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public List<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}

public class Contact
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public List<Email> EmailAddresses {get; set;}
}

public class Email
{
  public string EmailAddress {get; set;}
}


    private void TrimWhitespace(object instance)
    {
        if (instance != null)
        {
            var props = instance.GetType()
                    .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
                // Ignore indexers
                    .Where(prop => prop.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0)
                // Must be both readable and writable
                    .Where(prop => prop.CanWrite && prop.CanRead);

            foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
            {
                if (instance is IEnumerable)
                {
                    foreach (var item in (IEnumerable)instance)
                    {
                        TrimWhitespace(item);
                    }
                }
                else if (prop.GetValue(instance, null) is string)
                {
                    string value = (string)prop.GetValue(instance, null);
                    if (value != null)
                    {
                        value = value.Trim();
                        prop.SetValue(instance, value, null);
                    }
                }
                else 
                    TrimWhitespace(prop.GetValue(instance, null));
            }
        }
    }
```

Thoughts?